# Getting Claims from ADFS 3.0 and Displaying To Shibboleth 2.6 Service Provider (SP) in SAML 2.0

Tags: saml-2.0, windows-server-2012-r2, shibboleth, adfs3.0

I'm trying to configure **Windows Server 2012 r2 ADFS 3.0** to send the `NameID` to **Shibboleth 2.6 SAML 2.0 SP**, but I keep on getting these errors:

```
2016-11-15 10:07:07 WARN Shibboleth.AttributeResolver.Query [1]: can't attempt attribute query, either no NameID or no metadata to use
2016-11-15 10:07:07 INFO Shibboleth.SessionCache [1]: new session created: ID (_7e425978e43bc32c86393f518b26eb3e) IdP (https://c-adfs01.contoso.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml) Protocol(urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol) Address (192.168.50.131)
```

I understand that this has something to do about passing the `NameID` attribute from the **ADFS IDP** and displaying the `nameID` in **Shibboleth SAML 2.0 SP**.

I've also read that you need to set a rule in **ADFS IDP** to pass the `Email Address`, and transform the `Email address` to become a `NameID`. I have done that, and have these rules:

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress");
```

However, I have observed that the configuration seems compatible only with SAML 1.0, but not 2.0 (maybe).

So, I went on by adding the name attributes. I tried `transient`, `persistent`, and `emailAddress`, and trying both `SAML 1.0` and `SAML 2.0` configurations.

```
<Attribute name="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" id="NameID"/>
<Attribute name="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" id="NameID"/>
<Attribute name="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" id="NameID"/>
```

**Question:**

So, what is the proper way of configuring **ADFS IDP** to send the `NameID` to the **Shibboleth SP** and display the Session attribute when going to my **application Session page**?

Specifically, what is the proper output for `Claim Rules` that I should expect? and how should the XML configuration for Shibboleth `attribute-map.xml` look like?

```
https://c-app01.contoso.com/Shibboleth.sso/Session
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

The solution is to **create two rules inside "Issuance Transform Rules"** tab in the **Relying Party**. Here are the Rules to be set:

- Add a Rule to **Send LDAP Attributes as Claims**
- Add a Rule to **Transform an Incoming Claim**

Also, make sure that **Permit Access to All Users** is inside **Issuance Authorization Rules** tab.

---

**Instructions:**

**Add a Rule to Send LDAP Attributes as Claims:**

- Claim Rule Name: Email
- Attribute Store: Active Directory
- Mapping of LDAP: E-mail-Address to E-mail Address

This will map the Email address.

**Add a rule to Transform An Incoming Claim:**

- Claim rule name: EmailToNameID
- Incoming Claim Type: E-Mail Address
- Outgoing Claim Type: Name ID
- Outgoing Name ID Format: Email
- Make sure "Pass Through Claim Values" is selected.

The setting above for "Transform An Incoming Claim" will give you the following claim rule:

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"]
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier", Issuer = c.Issuer, OriginalIssuer = c.OriginalIssuer, Value = c.Value, ValueType = c.ValueType, Properties["http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claimproperties/format"] = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress");
```

After that, you may configure the `attribute-map.xml` like so:

```
<Attribute name="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" id="Email"/>
```

---

**My Mistake:**

I found out that every setting in my Claims Rules is correct, except that the rules for `Email` and `EmailToNameID` should be under the **Issuance Transform Rules** Tab of the **Relying Party**.